# Show/Hide div id from input value form previous page

Tags: javascript, php, html, show, hidden

I find it difficult to solve this problem. I want to use the form input data data from the previous page to show or hide a particular div id.

```
<form action="http://example.com/example/" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" id="example" name="example" value="<?php echo $site; ?>">
          <input class="examplesubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

page 2

```
<div id="testing"  style="display:none;">
content
</div>
```

I want the input value or name or id, of the previous page to be used as the basis of div id showing or hidden. if the user hits the submit button, the page automatically displays the content, otherwise the content is not displayed

how should i write it? may use javascript or php code

Comment: Have you written any server-side code so far to try to solve this issue?

Comment: I'd put it in the arguments of url, like `site.xz/form/page2/?whatever=yes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would achieve that in a manner like so:

**Page 1**

```
<form action="index2.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="example" name="example" value="foo">
    <input class="examplesubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Page 2** (index2.php)

```
<div id="testing"<?php echo ($_POST['example'] == 'foo') ? '' : ' style="display:none;"'; ?>>
    konten
</div>
```

This makes use of the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) which is more or less an inline if/else condition.

So the form on page 1, submits to the form on page 2 (index2.php) in my example and checks that the form field with the name of example has a value set to "foo".

Comment: value is dynamic, I want to use the dynamic value. How to?

Answer (score 0):

You can include both in same page only, hide the content default by hidden, show only be click the submit button.

```
<form action="http://example.com/example/" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" id="example" name="example" value="<?php echo $site; ?>">
          <input class="examplesubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here you have  the include the second page, into first page only here by using

```
<?php require_once 'page2.php'; ?>
```

Here is jquery or javascript, sorry i mostly prefer jquery.

```
<script>
$(function(){
 $("#testing").hide();
   $('.examplesubmit').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#testing").show();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried it but it does not work. I use wordpress platform .. in this case page.php to single php. I want the div to appear when the user clicks the submit button and when not, the content is not displayed. I tried to use the foo method suggested by WebCode.ie user. yes it works if the value is fixed but I use the dynamics value when applied to not work. 3 more days for this problem makes me frustrated :(